# ¿Existe una palabra para los pitidos o zumbidos en los oídos?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Todos hemos experimentado esa sensación alguna vez, como cuando estas durante un tiempo en un ambiente ruidoso (una discoteca o concierto, por ejemplo) y luego vuelves a casa y tus oídos te zumban en señal de protesta.

¿Existe algún término en español para referirse a dicha sensación?

Answer (score 4):

Sí, el diccionario recoge la voz latina ***[tinnitus](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZnSFPo3)***, la cual redirige a su vez a esta otra voz:

> **[acúfeno](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0ep8GUP)**
>
> Del it. *acufene*, y este del gr. *ἀκούειν akoúein* 'oír' y *φαίνειν phaínein* 'aparecer'.
>
> 1. m. Med. Sensación auditiva que consiste en percibir sonidos que no proceden de fuentes externas.

Comment: Tinnitus es el término que usan los médicos y del que siempre te previenen en las escuelas de buceo ya que te puede pasar si realizas un ascenso rápido. Acúfeno es completamente nuevo para mi. Bueno haberlo aprendido hoy. +1